# Writing data by groups while skipping the group column

Tags: r

I want to write the data frame in separate files by its groups but at the same time I don't want to the files to have the column which contains the group info.

For example, in the code below, I don't want the gear column in each separate file.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars |> 
  group_by(gear) |> 
  do(write.table(., paste0(unique(.$gear), "_.txt"),
               sep = "\t", row.names = F, col.names = F))
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could also use the (experimental) `group_walk`:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars |>
 group_by(gear) |>
 group_walk(~ write.table(.x,
                          file = paste0(.y$gear, "_.txt"),
                          sep = "\t",
                          row.names = FALSE,
                          col.names = FALSE)
            )
```

> .y to refer to the key
>
> .x to refer to the subset of rows of .tbl for the given group.

The parameter `.keep` is `FALSE` by default.

Answer (score 2):

We can `split` by the 'gear' column and use `imap` to loop over the named `list` for writing

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mtcars %>%{
   split(.[-10], .$gear)
    } %>%
   imap(~ write.table(.x, paste0(.y, "_.txt"),
   sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE))
```

If we want to return the dataset after writing, can also use `group_modify`

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>% 
  group_modify(~  {
   write.table(.x, paste0(.y, "_.txt"),
   sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
  .x})
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! Can you help me better understand what .x and .y works?

Comment: @Yaaman sorry, didn't see your edit.  `imap` returns the value  of list in .x and the names of the list (if absent the sequence of the list) in .y.  `split` returns a named list

Comment: @akrun Why the curly parenthesis? Many thanks.

Comment: @TarJae because there are more than one statement i.e. `write.table` and returning the original data `.x`